# How can we treat the generator of a discrete-time Markov chain as the generator of a Markov-jump process?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, semigroups-of-operators

In the popular paper [*Weak Convergence and Optimal Scaling of Random Walk Metropolis Algorithms*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1034625254) by Roberts, Gelman and Gilks, the authors state (see below) that "in the Skorokhod topology, it does not cause any problems to treat $G_n$ as a continuous time generator (of a process with jumps at times of a Poisson process at rate $n$)."

What exactly do they mean? First of all, in the generator they present for $X^n$ there is a factor of $n$ which shouldn't be there, should it? However, it's clear to me that if we take a poisson process $N$ with rate $n$, then the generator of $\left(X^n_{N_t}\right)_{t\ge0}$ is exactly the generator they present for $X^n$. So, is that what they mean?

And how exactly does this help in order to prove the theorem? I see the problem that $Z^n$ is a Markov process, while $U^n$ is not. They aim to use the convergence result in [Chapter 4, Corollary 8.7, of Ethier and Kurtz](https://books.google.de/books?id=zvE9RFouKoMC&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232&dq=%22Note+that+D+in+that+chapter%27s+Theorem+9.4%22&source=bl&ots=7axHr2U1xx&sig=dy9olTBRFxLFEzErzk_sdvqax1E&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlxJX2y_DeAhWQyqQKHZWDAckQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Note%20that%20D%20in%20that%20chapter's%20Theorem%209.4%22&f=false). Why is that possible?

Roberts, Gelman and Gilks:
[image: Roberts, Gelman and Gilks]